# CONCATENATE and TEXTJOIN formulas / Excel / VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, textjoin

I'm having again some problems. Here's the deal:

[image]

I'd like to use the TEXTJOIN function to concatenate all the elements within the range A:G, skiping the potential empty cells.
The problem is, I have to follow a certain order... This is what the H column indicates : a key where each letter represents a colum

My idea was to use this formula :

**=CONCATENER("=";"JOINDRE.TEXTE("" - "";VRAI;";STXT(H2;1;1);LIGNE(H2);";";STXT(H2;2;1);LIGNE(H2);";";STXT(H2;3;1);LIGNE(H2);";";STXT(H2;4;1);LIGNE(H2);";";STXT(H2;5;1);LIGNE(H2);";";STXT(H2;6;1);LIGNE(H2);";";STXT(H2;7;1);LIGNE(H2);")")**

(I know, it looks so bad haha)

And then copy and paste it in values in another cell to do the trick (= the actual resultat of the textjoin formula).
Unfortunately that idea doesn't work...

I also tried to use the formula without the brackets around my separator in the textjoin formula and then replace " - " by "" - "" with a macro but it does not seem to work as well...

Any clue?

Thanks guys, and thanks to the ppl who already helped me in this post:
[VBA - Count empty cols, search and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173867/vba-count-empty-cols-search-and-replace)

Jean

Comment: Does you column H always has the 7 Column names? If so you could use a combination of `INDIRECT` using in order `MID` to extract each part of the column name and `ROW` for the row number and then just join all 5 pieces with `&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Textjoin function you're looking for:

```
 =TEXTJOIN("-",TRUE,INDIRECT(MID(H2,1,1)&ROW(H2)),INDIRECT(MID(H2,2,1)&ROW(H2)),INDIRECT(MID(H2,3,1)&ROW(H2)),INDIRECT(MID(H2,4,1)&ROW(H2)),INDIRECT(MID(H2,5,1)&ROW(H2)),INDIRECT(MID(H2,6,1)&ROW(H2)),INDIRECT(MID(H2,7,1)&ROW(H2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alongside Mister 832 great answer, here is a (possible) alternative solution for those who don't have Excel 2016 *Textjoin* function.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(INDIRECT(MID(H2;1;1)&ROW(H2))&" "&INDIRECT(MID(H2;2;1)&ROW(H2))&" "&INDIRECT(MID(H2;3;1)&ROW(H2))&" "&INDIRECT(MID(H2;4;1)&ROW(H2))&" "&INDIRECT(MID(H2;5;1)&ROW(H2))&" "&INDIRECT(MID(H2;6;1)&ROW(H2))&" "&INDIRECT(MID(H2;7;1)&ROW(H2));"  ";" ")
```